# Updating SQLite row using update method

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to update a row in SQLite on android using the update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) method. I have seen many sources on this cite and else where around the web describing how to do so but it does not seem to be working. My main problem is my lack of understanding of the last two variables that are passed into the method do and how to properly set them up.

String whereClause: What does this do? Passing null, changes all the values in a column but what if you wanted to just switch one row at for example row "x" in the sql database; how would that be done?
String[] whereArgs: What does this do?

Code

```
//how do you edit variable NOTE_TEXT at pos to be editedNote        
public void editNotes(int pos, String editedNote){
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            String postion = Integer.toString(pos);

            ContentValues newContentValues = new ContentValues();
            newContentValues.put(NoteDBHelper.NOTE_TEXT, editedNote);

        db.update(  "noteTable", newContentValues, NoteDBHelper.NOTE_TEXT + " = " + postion, null);
   }

static class NoteDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "noteDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "noteTable";
    private static final String UID = "_id";
    private static final String NOTE_TEXT = "note";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "";

   /* private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +
            " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOTE_TEXT +
            " VARCHAR(255), );";*/
   private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOTE_TEXT + " VARCHAR(255)  );";

    public NoteDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WHERE clause is the filter for your query. 
Normal WHERE clauses look something like this

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = value
WHERE column_name1 = value1 AND/OR column_name2 = value2 AND/OR...
```

The db.update() does the first step for you when you pass it a table name. The `String whereClause` is the `column_name1=` part and `value1` would be put in the `String[] whereArgs` spot.
The `String[] whereArgs` can be passed a `null` option as long as your `String whereClause` has the full option of `column_name1 = value1` clause.

The `whereClause` acts as a filter to limit which rows are changed by the UPDATE statement.

If you wanted to set one row to 'x' you would do it like this:

```
String whereClause = "note = \"the\"";
db.update("noteTable", "x", whereClause, null);
```

This would update all rows where the 'note' column contains the value "the".

Comment: Sorry I guess I worded my question wrong. What I meant by "x" was a row in the data such as the first row "x = 1 , second "x =2" or another row. Is it possible to do it that way

Comment: @Neil M. 
As in automatically increment? If that's the case, when you create the UID column, you already have it automatically increment. 
So, the ID for each row will be unique.

Comment: @NeilM. If you wanted to find the column where the ID is 2, your `String whereClause = UID + " = 2"`

Answer (score 1):

An update to Rhuarc13's answer:

```
String whereClause = "position = ?";
String[] values = new String[]{position};
db.update(TABLE_NAME, newContentValues, whereClause, values);
```

That way you don't have to worry about escaping characters and such with the where clause.  Also `update` requires a `ContentValues` for the second parameter, not a String, so as written his answer won't work.

However, you don't seem to have a "position" field in your table.  The id field may or may not correspond to the row's position in the table, so you should not rely on that.  If you have a way to get the id, that's fine, otherwise you'll want another field that you can set to the correct value to reflect that row's position, and use that for your update.

EDIT: If you want to query by id:

```
String whereClause = UID + " = ?";
String[] values = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
db.update(TABLE_NAME, newContentValues, whereClause, values);
```

Comment: Okay thanks. So if I wanted it to go to the _id field that is equal to 2 for example I would replace the ? with 2. Sorry if that is a dumb question I am new to SQLite and don't yet understand the syntax.

Comment: See my edit.  If the variable `id` has the value 2, that would update the row having id = 2 with whatever values you put in `newContentValues`.

Comment: This happens to work because `_id` has integer affinity, but in general, using string parameters for numeric values does not work correctly.

Comment: There is no choice in the matter, `update` requires a String[] for parameter values.  I'll update to add conversion logic though.